# CSS: tint circular div on hover? Only tinting behind div?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to tint a circular div on hover (as in keep its original color but add a black transparent tint over it). I have a three.js in a div that is within another div to create a circular affect, and then have created an additional div around this:

```
<ul>
        <!-- <li>-->
       <div class = "overlay"><a href="polyGalaxy/index.html"><div class ="circle1">
        <div id ="btn1"></div>
        </div>
        </a></div>
        <!--</li>
        <li>
        <div class ="circle2">
        <div id ="btn2"></div>
        </div>
        </li>-->
        </ul>
```

I have attempted to create a tint using this:

```
.overlay:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 5;
}
.circle1 {
    background: #50a3a2;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
    display: table;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 50px auto;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
#btn1 {

    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align:center;
    left:0%;
    position:relative; /*makes left effective*/
    display:table-cell;
}
```

however overlay is only tinting BEHIND the circular div. I know this because when I delete the `border-radius`, I get this:
[image]

How can I tint a circular div on hover?

Comment: Your code does not work because background is the lowest layer of an element AFAIK - you need to add that background tint to an element that is *above* the circle object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create that effect using a pseudo element which has an `rgba` background-color (tint) that fades on hover:

```css
.circle1 {
  background: #50a3a2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #50a3a2 0%, #53e3a6 100%);
  display: table;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.circle1::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  border-radius: inherit;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.circle1:hover::after {opacity:1;}
```

```html
<div class="circle1">
  <div id="btn1"></div>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/9zn3mpa4/